# await ExecuteNonQueryAsync() still blocks my UI

Tags: c#, sql, asynchronous, netezza

I find that my C# app UI hangs when calling an async method, I cannot figure out why.

```
private async void selectCSVFileButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ... 
    var results = await ntz.getProductNames();
    ...
}
...
public async Task<List<string[]>> getProductNames()
{
    string fmt = "DRIVER={{NetezzaSQL}};SERVER={0};PORT={1};DATABASE={2};UID={3};PWD={4};";
    ntz = new OdbcConnection(string.Format(fmt, server, port, db, user, password));
    await ntz.OpenAsync();
    qry = "SELECT * FROM ak_db_1 WHERE prod_name_desc='Unknown'";
    OdbcCommand cmd = ntz.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandTimeout = 600;
    cmd.CommandText = qry;
    await cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync();
    ...
}
```

My application hangs completely (UI unresponsive) until the cmd.ExecuteNonQueryAsync completes.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Per [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.odbccommand(v=vs.110).aspx) for `OdbcCommand.ExecuteNonQueryAsync`:

> Providers should override with an appropriate implementation. The cancellation token may optionally be ignored. **The default implementation invokes the synchronous ExecuteNonQuery method and returns a completed task, blocking the calling thread.**

Derived commands (such as `SqlCommand` for SQL Server) *do* override this so the command executes asynchronously.

If you want to avoid blocking the UI thread, then you'll have to execute this on a thread pool thread:

```
var results = await Task.Run(() => ntz.getProductNames());
```

Given the asynchronous methods aren't implemented and simply delegate to their synchronous equivalents, it may make sense to change `getProductNames` to use the synchronous method in the first place.

Comment: Thank you very much Charles, I completely missed that!

Answer (score 0):

try to add this, instead `await ntz.OpenAsync();.`

```
await Task.StartNew(ntz.Open);
```

Comment: Do you mean `Task.Run()` or `Task.Factory.StartNew()`?